# How can I pipe a media file from one server to another server using node, and not using .then syntax?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have `file-server` and `file-receiver`. I want to get a file from `file-server` and upload it to `file-receiver` via a stream pipe. Not sure how to do this in node.

Pseudo code of what I want to achieve:

```
image_url = `${file_server.url}/mediauuid/a_uuid`
somestream = somestream
let getRes = await fetch(image_url).pipe(somestream)

upload_url = `${file_receiver}/media`
opts = {
  headers: { "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"}
  body: somestream
}
let putRes = await fetch(upload_url, opts)
console.log("happy days")
```

Doesnt seem like `fetch` has a pipe method. Would prefer to stay away from `.then` chaining if possible as I find it to be quite an unreadable syntax.

Comment: No, `fetch` does not have a `pipe` method, it takes a request and returns a promise for a response! If you want to somehow use streams with it, you'll have to pass a readable stream as the body of the request, or you'll have to read from response body as a stream.

Comment: I don't get your pseudocode. What do the two requests (one to `image_url` and one to `upload_url`) have to do with each other? Are those two separate attempts to do the same thing? Where does `somestream` come from? `somestream = somestream` doesn't make any sense even in pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to somehow "allocate" `somestream` and then "pipe" the GET response into it. You can just access the stream [as `.body` on the response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/body). Then feed that into the upload:

```
const image_url = `${file_server.url}/mediauuid/a_uuid`;
const getRes = await fetch(image_url);
if (!getRes.ok) throw new Error('GETting image failed');

const upload_url = `${file_receiver}/media`;
const putRes = await fetch({
  url: upload_url,
  method: 'PUT', // or POST?
  headers: {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"},
  body: getRes.body,
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^
});
if (!putRes.ok) throw new Error('PUTting image failed');
console.log("happy days")
```

Comment: I see. Would this not result in this block behaving synchronously? ie it would first await the full fetch when downloading into memory, and only then start the uploading? Ideally I would want the upload to start as soon as there is something to upload, in case it is a large file, it can download and upload simultaneously.

Comment: Okay I think I understand, the `await` only waits for the stream to start, then body is of type Readable and the code execution continues, which is why it is always necessary to also `await` the eg `res.json()` calls. Cool, didnt fully understand that. Thanks!